# Custom validation of mongoose's Schema params

Tags: validation, mongoose, schema

have the next params of object:

```
var mongoose = require (PATH);
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var schema - new Schema ({

barcode:{
type:number,
required:true,
unique:true

},...});
```

i want to validate 'barcode', which will be no less and no more than 14 characters;

for this i write the code below:

```
schema.path('barcode').validate(function(barcode){
return barcode.length == 13;
}, 'sorry, the error occurred, be careful while typing, 14 characters only!");

exports.Item = mongoose.model('Item', schema);
```

But when i implement this schema to the concrete object, this validation does not play any role. I mean, that i can type any length of number and no any error occur!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [mongoose-validator](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose-validator). It integrates with `mongoose` to support custom validation. You can use it something like this.

```
var validate = require('mongoose-validator').validate;

var BarcodeSchema = new Schema({
 code: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    validate: validate('len', 13)
 }
});
```